# How to extract country from user localization data (using Python/ PowerBI)

Tags: python, pandas, localization, location

So basicly as u probably know Twitter reduced acces to their API thats why I downloaded Kaggle data for my analysis with contains location passed by the user. I want to get column "Country".
My data looks like this:

```
1                     United Kingdom
2                        Chicago, IL
3                    Zambia mufulira
4                 New Hampshire, USA
8                 Kingsbridge, Devon
13                             yukon
20                       El Salvador
21                  Attock, Pakistan
23              Southern California 
26                            Uganda
28               localhost,Polokwane
29                    秒ファボ多いですごめんね！！
30                       Butuan City
32                   Los Angeles, CA
33    Cambridge. February the 19th. 
34                 Recently returned
37                                 
38                 Infinity & Beyond
41                             Lagos
```

Is there any library tahts can help me with task of predicting probability of specific country? or u guys know some some approach to solve this problem using python?

I put the this data to Power BI and its looks fine, but is there way to exstract this data from plot and save it as "Country"?

[Power BI Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF7XQ.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF7XQ.png)